# print table row mysql python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am writing logs in mysql database and I create a table `coordinates`, with the columns `Id`, `x`, `y`. When I want to read from the db, I want to print the latest log each time:

```
cursor.execute("Select x,y from coordinates ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row[0])
```

It always returns the first row in the log which is not ordered by DESC. It seems that `fetchall` changes the order of the log. Is there any solution?

Comment: How do you identify that it returns the first row and not the last row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code returns only last row because you requested for only 1 item:

```
"Select x,y from coordinates ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"
# You asked your database to return just one record ^
```

Since, you have already mentioned in the query `ORDER BY id DESC`, it will return value based on decreasing order of id. May be you checked the wrong data.

Also, you print just the value of `x`, because again your code asked for that:

```
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row[0]) 
    #         ^ item at 0th index
```

In order to get all the values of both `x` and `y`, do:

```
for x, y in cursor.fetchall():
    print("x= ", x, ", y= ", y) 

# OR,
# for row in cursor.fetchall():
#     print("x= ", row[0], ", y= ", row[1])
```